# Erro ao acessar arquivo.js externo

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma página em ASP.NET MVC e dentro da tag Body preciso por o seguinte javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/loader-scripts/4a756f5f-544e-4ae6-af72-956443dd4124-loader.js"></script>
```

Mas esta chamada retorna o seguinte erro:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).
Já coloquei `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` e ainda continua o erro.

Comment: Já tentou baixar o arquivo JS e guardar no seu próprio servidor e de lá fazer a chamada?

Comment: Marcus, já tentei sim e o erro continua.